# Why can't I load .gltf model in WebXR Ar Core base example?

Tags: html, three.js, augmented-reality, arcore, webxr

I followed this Google's tutorial: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/webxr/hello-webxr?hl=pt-br and successfully made a scene that recgonizes planes in real world, displays a reticle above it and when clicked, show the sunflower model, as it seems in this tutorial. Now I want to load my own .gltf model. I made my GitHub repository and uploaded my .gltf and .bin files generated in Blender, but when I change the URL of the sunflower that was in tutorial for my uploaded model URL, nothing happens when I click on screen, the model isn't displayed on scene. Here are some parts of the code that handles it:

Here I add the GLTF Loader from three.js:

```
<!-- three.js -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.0/build/three.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.0/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
```

Here I add the .gltf model URL:

```
let model;
loader.load("https://github.com/joaopedrovga/GltfModels/blob/main/GLTF/SensiaParis_GLTF.gltf", function(gltf) {
  model = gltf.scene;
});
```

And here I add the touch event listener:

```
session.addEventListener("select", (event) => {
  if (model) {
    const clone = model.clone();
    clone.position.copy(reticle.position);
    scene.add(clone);
  }
});
```

I don't have much experience with code so I hope someone can help me this, please! Thanks!